# Which header fields characterize a packet as unique?

Tags: tcp, header, udp, ip, packets

I'm dealing with **IP** packets which might contain **UDP** or **TCP** payloads.

If we only consider IP-level and transport-level **headers**, what could be a **set of representative fields** for one packet? That is, which header fields, considered as a whole, would make that packet unique? (in absence of duplicates, of course)

If we didn't consider the IP and TCP or UDP `chksum` fields, would a subset of the other fields be enough?

Answer (score 1):

IP and UDP don't have a concept of "uniqueness".  TCP does, implied by the sequence-number field.  There aren't enough fields to make it clear when a packet gets duplicated or dropped in transit.

**Update based on comments:**

If you're writing both the sending and receiving code, you could include an IP option that identifies the packet uniquely.  I'd recommend using the SATNET StreamId option (#8, see [RFC 791](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt), section 3.1) - it gives you 16 bits to work with and it's been around for over 30 years.

If you're not writing the sending code, I don't think you can do this - there just aren't any fields to base the comparison on in IP, ICMP, or UDP.

Comment: Yes, of course. My wording was a bit poor. What I ultimately meant was: if I disregard all checksums (IP and transport layer), which partly depend on the respective payloads, do all the other header fields (or a subset of them) identify the packet? Just imagine I can't look at the transport layer payload. Also, to make it simpler, let's pretend duplicates don't exist.

Comment: I noticed that the TCP sequence number gets occasionally overwritten by middle boxes, so I would like to not consider it. I guess this makes it a bit impossible to achieve my goal...

Comment: You haven't really described your goal.  You've asked a question, to which the answer is "you can't do that".  What do you mean when you say "identify the packet"?

Comment: I have to compare the payload of ttl expired ICMP packets with the packets that generated them. My problem is that sometimes middleboxes apply changes in the IP header and also on the TCP sequence field. That is why occasionally I cant directly find a match for these ICMP packets with anything. A slight change in the header also means a slightly different checksum value and that's the reason I have to disregard it in this comparison process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the optional field of IP Header to append data for uniqueness (if you're sending) but you need to modify IHL to greater than 5.